# Cut user shape out of circle in SVG using a mask

Tags: svg

I got an icon from our designer to add to our custom icon font. The icon should be a circle with a cutout of a user. Unfortunately the designer didn't follow some fontcustom guidelines, like no opacity and only use 1 color. The user cutout was white on a black circle. Now I'm trying to cut the user out of the circle using a mask. This is what I tried:

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="hole">
        <circle cx="12" cy="9" r="3" stroke="black"/>
        <path d="M17 17C17 14.2386 14.7614 12 12 12C9.23858 12 7 14.2386 7 17" stroke="black"/>
    </mask>
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="black" mask="url(#hole)"/>
</svg>
```

Now somehow, the complete circle dissapears. I tried playing around with a fill instead of a stroke, which didn't work. I also tried changing the stroke to white, but that just gives me the part of the user icon that is within the circle (which is the complete user).

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="hole">
        <circle cx="12" cy="9" r="3" stroke="white"/>
        <path d="M17 17C17 14.2386 14.7614 12 12 12C9.23858 12 7 14.2386 7 17" stroke="white"/>
    </mask>
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="black" mask="url(#hole)"/>
</svg>
```

How can I get my user to be cut out of the circle? I don't get why the mask won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a mask, white means opaque (solid) and black means transparent (hole).

So if you want to make a mask with a shape cut out of it, the background of the mask has to be white, and the hole parts should be black.

Like this:

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="hole">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <circle cx="12" cy="9" r="3" stroke="black"/>
        <path d="M17 17C17 14.2386 14.7614 12 12 12C9.23858 12 7 14.2386 7 17" stroke="black"/>
    </mask>
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="black" mask="url(#hole)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: So basically you first have to add a background to whatever you want to be inside the mask?

Comment: Only if you want to cut a hole out of something.  You wouldn't need it if you were, say, just wanting to make the outside of something circular.